# Is (o-)minimality preserved by elementary equivalence?

Tags: logic, model-theory, quantifier-elimination

Consider two structures which are elementary equivalent. If one is minimal/o-minimal, can the same be said about the other?

The pooint is that one cannot quantify over sets (in first-order logic), but perhaps definable sets are "special". As an example, I believe that in some cases of models of theories which admit quantifier elimination, such as Real Closed Fields, the conclusion is true.

Nevertheless, I fail to find an exhaustive approach to the problem.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: With regard to the first sentence of the second paragraph, you might find the following useful: Definable sets (with parameters) come in families $\{\varphi(M,b)\mid b\in M\}$, where $M$ is a model. While you can't quantify over all definable sets, you can "quantify" over all of the sets in a family by quantifying over the parameters $b$. So, for example, you can try writing down a sentence asserting that any definable set of the form $\varphi(M,b)$ for some $b$ can be decomposed as a union of at most $k$ intervals.

Comment: Since you can do this for every formula $\varphi(x,y)$ with a specified "object variable" $x$ and parameter variables $y$, you can start to see how a first-order theory can express things like strong minimality and o-minimality. The problem is that "every definable set is a union of finitely many intervals" can't be expressed unless there is an upper bound on the number of intervals for each family. So the main work in showing that o-minimality is preserved by elementary equivalence comes down to proving that any o-minimal structure has such a bound for every family.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O-minimality is preserved by elementary equivalence (it is in "Definable sets in ordered structures II" by Knight, Pillay and Steinhorn, thanks to Alex Kruckman for the reference).

Minimality however is not preserved. E.g. every definable set in $(\mathbb N, <)$ is finite or cofinite, I think it has quantifier elimination in the language where you add $0$ and the successor function $s(x) = x+1$. However it has order, so is unstable and therefore not all models are minimal.

This is the reason that there is a notion of "strong minimality" which says that a structure and all structures elementarily equivalent to it are minimal.

Comment: A more precise reference: *Definable sets in ordered structures II* by **Knight**, Pillay, and Steinhorn.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks! Edited the answer.